# mySQL database with Flask - Internal Servor Error

Tags: mysql, flask, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to allow users to save their systems on a web app that I am creating so that other users can browse through them, with tags to categorize the systems. Here's what I have so far:

### app.py

```
from flask import Flask, request
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from contextlib import closing
from datetime import datetime

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql://root:password@localhost/OFFLsystems'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

tags = db.Table('tags',
    db.Column('tag_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('tag.tag_id')),
    db.Column('system_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('system.system_id')))

class System(db.Model):
    system_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    system_name = db.Column(db.String(80))
    system_description = db.Column(db.String(400))
    tags = db.relationship('Tag', secondary=tags,backref=db.backref('systems', lazy='dynamic'))
    system_date_created = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    system_file = db.Column(db.String(4000))

class Tag(db.Model):
    tag_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

@app.route("/", methods=['GET','POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        name = request.form['name']
        desc = request.form['description']
        tags = request.form['tags']
        date = datetime.utcnow()
        sys_file = request.form['file']
        system = System(name,desc,tags,date,sys_file)
        db.session.add(system)
        db.session.commit()
        return render_template("index.html")
    return render_template("index.html")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Database Tests</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="POST">
Name:<input type="text" name="name">
<br>
Description:<input type="textarea" name="description">
<br>
Tags:<input type="text" name="tags">
<br>
File:<input type="text" name="file">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Problem:** I'm getting an internal server error and can't pinpoint where this is happening. I suspect it may have something to do with the *db.session.add(system)* and *db.session.commit()* lines since I've only seen those used in command line, is a different command supposed to be used when implementing it inside of the program?

Comment: please do this `app.run(debug = True)` if you want to see error message.

Answer (score 0):

In the `system = System(name,desc,tags,date,sys_file)` constructor, try passing through keyword arguments

```
system = System(system_name=name, system_description=desc,...)
```